# Change style of Leaflet Draw rectangle while drawing

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet Draw to draw rectangles on a Leaflet map. The rectangles get added to a FeatureGroup once they are created, and their styles are updated based on their size. For example, the rectangles are filled red if their area exceeds a certain threshold and green if their area is within the threshold.

I'm leveraging the "draw:created" callback to inspect the completed rectangle's size. I'm also able to update the rectangle's style during editing by leveraging the "draw:editresize" and "draw:editmove" callbacks. By doing this, users can easily see if their rectangles fall within the correct area requirements while they are resizing them.

Here is my problem: I haven't been able to find a callback that allows me to style the rectangle *during its initial creation*. Have I overlooked a callback? I've tried all of the logical ones from the doc's: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event.

There's not really any code to show other than the following event handlers, which currently work while editing a rectangle.

```
this.map.on('draw:editmove', function (e) {
    self.setROIStyle(e);// works
});

this.map.on('draw:editresize', function (e) {
        self.setROIStyle(e);//works
});
```

Thanks,
Ray